# Is $X_n=\frac{x^n}{n(n+1)}$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Is the series $X_n=\frac{x^n}{n(n+1)}$ convergent or divergent?

I thought of it in this way:

The numerator converges to $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and the denominator diverges.  Therefore the series converges to $0$?

I am new to this, any help with the correct approach to solve such questions will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking about $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$

Answer (score 1):

If $|x| \leq 1$,
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n(n+1)}\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}=1$$
Hence the series converges.

Otherwise,
$\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n$ diverges and the series sum therefore diverges.